# Can you have fallbacks for the poster attribute?

Tags: html, css, video, fallback, webp

I was wondering if anyone knows if it's possible to have a fallback image for the `poster` attribute in the `video` tag. I couldn't find anything about it.

Currently I'm just using a png, but I'd love to use a webp so the page can load faster. The poster is just there for slow connections when lazy loading, so that the page still makes sense and can be read without the video ever loading. So the image has to be of high enough quality in case the video never loads and as it's a portfolio website, there's only so much quality I can sacrifice. Looking to have a fallback as Safari still doesn't support webP.

Unless there's another image format that I've missed that has universal support (at least with modern browsers) that has comparable compression.

Comment: You could use a server side detection like described here: http://www.stucox.com/blog/client-side-vs-server-side-detection-for-webp/#server-side-detection

Comment: @yunzen Thanks for that resource, that might be possible for me to implement it that way, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I tried also without success: it seems that the fallback is only displayed on old browsers only  and not on the récents: Otherwise it is necessary to manage in js the non loading of the video